# Predis \ Connection \ ConnectionException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to run laravel shop menu project on my local machin in xampp. But when I try to run it show me below error. Please help me to solve this problem.
I have also attached a screen shot for more clearification.

Thanks in advance:

### Error:

```
Predis \ Connection \ ConnectionException
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. [tcp://tunnel.pagodabox.com:6379]

open: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel-shop-menu\vendor\predis\predis\lib\Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection.php
     * Helper method to handle connection errors.
     *
     * @param string $message Error message.
     * @param int    $code    Error code.
     */
    protected function onConnectionError($message, $code = null)
    {
        CommunicationException::handle(new ConnectionException($this, "$message [{$this->parameters->scheme}://{$this->getIdentifier()}]", $code));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `tunnel.pagodabox.com` does not have a valid corresponding DNS entry in the associated nameservers, therefore it's unable to resolve it to an IP address with which it can then attempt to connect over port `6379`.

Either use the IP directly or give that subdomain a resolvable DNS entry in the Nameservers.